# What are the cf:before and cf:after resets doing in responsive web design

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive website at the moment and im trying to work up my CSS at the moment. One thing ive noticed is a lot of sites ive looked at use:

```
cf:before, .cf:after {
content: " ";
display: block;
height: 0;
min-height: 0 !important;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

And all their elements in the responsive site use an extra class of cf which im guessing stands for clear float, even though the elements as far as i can see are not floated? Can anyone help me understand why they are being used. For instance: http://www.londonandpartners.com/

Thanks
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you have to know about cf (clearfix) :
[Clearfix Meaning and why do we use it](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/clearfix_block-formatting-context_and_hasLayout.asp)
[Clearfix Reloaded cf:before / cf:after](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/)
I think it is the best way to know why do we use it.

Comment: I've used the micro version on a few projects and found it has worked well and is much smaller code: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/